# how to generate array tensor in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I generated input tensor A tensor using the following codes in tensorflow;

```
import tensorflow as tf

A = tf.constant(1.0, shape = [10, 10])
with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(sess.run(A))
output = [[ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.  1.]]
```

I want to set parts of the entries to zero, say half or quarter along either the column or raw and I did the following;

```
import numpy as np
output = np.array(A)
A1 = output[:, output.shape[1]//2:] = 0
print(A1)
```

But I was getting error 'tuple index out of range' Please help
`print(sess.run(A1))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the single parts separately and then concatenate them:

```
A = tf.ones(shape=[10, 5])
B = tf.zeros(shape=[10,5])

AB = tf.concat((A,B), axis=1)
```

Same holds for a row-wise split.